# Android EditText - text move when showing top icon

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I am showing icons on EditText with method `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds()`, situation is following:

[image]

When I show top icon, text jumps / move down.

[image]

I set paddingTop & marginTop of editText as 0dp, but did not help. any ideas ?

`<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText_Search"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shadow"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/string_EditText_Hint_EnterFieldNumber"
        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textVisiblePassword"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:paddingLeft="12dp"
        android:paddingRight="12dp"
        android:textColor="@color/ForestGreen"
        android:textColorHint="@color/Silver"
        android:textColorLink="@color/White"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/black_cursor" >
    </EditText>`

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: how to prevent the text moved down when the tick icon appears

Comment: question is, why top icon moves text down, even there is space in edit text. what should i do to top icon dont move that text ?

Answer (score 1):

I would just use a different View.

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:src="@drawable/icon"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>
<EditText
    android:marginBottom="20dp"/>
```

assuming 20dp is your icon height. This way the EditText content will always stay centered in the box, and you can show/hide the icon by calling `imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` or `imageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)`.

Comment: will this automatically move up/down whole EditText when ImageView invisible/visible ?

Comment: there are a few problems with your answer: in the picture the `TextView` is  surrounded with a border...well the `ImageView` will be outside the border. 2nd: you are assuming size...it's much better to calculate the size programaticaly.  third: even without border the text is centered in the `TextView`. when the image is visible the text cannot be centered anymore

Comment: @ToKra good thing about visibility `View.INVISIBLE` is that the view height and width are still part of the layout, even if you can't see it. So when you set `View.VISIBLE` you are not adding something, but rather making it visible. No other element will move. Of course you will need an outer layout (i.e., the box) in which you can put both the `ImageView` and the `EditText`.

Answer (score 0):

you are setting the height of the `EditText` to constant thus you do not let it expand after adding the top compound.

it will not matter though because you will still need to adjust the bottom container. if you know the height of the the `Drawable`, just set `bottomPadding` to be equal (programmatic).

you can also cheat and set  a `drawable` as bottom one with `alpha` 0 or empty one

Comment: what should I set then ?

Comment: actually I am trying to set  android:paddingBottom but its really messy. are you saying that every time I show top icon, I should also count padding of bottom & set ? its really not straight forward, I thought it could be done easier.

Comment: there is no way to align in a simple matter. you can think of it as if the `drawable` is not part of the `TextView`, the `TextView` starts where the `drawable` finishes + `drawablePadding`

Comment: there could be option in xml definition to compute padding automaticaly & to fit without move text

Comment: seriously dude that is the least of your problems when programming in android. there are so many quirks and "guess how to do it yourself" or just plain "not working (PagerAdapter suck when trying to remove views)". there is a reason why there are more than 600000 questions under `android` tag